# Java-Creating tile map gif

Tags: java, image, image-processing, game-engine

I am trying to figure out how I can take a given image file(JPG, GIF, etc) and cut a certain part of it out and then creating an image in my program and the pasting the part that was cut out column by column and row by row in a repeating format. I basically want to create a game "map" image from tiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Java's BufferedImage class to load and split up the image.

To load the image you can use:

```
try {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("path_to_file.ext"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then you can use the sub image method to divide up the image:

```
BufferedImage square1 = image.getSubimage(x, y, width, height);
```

For more info on the BufferedImage class you can check [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html)

You can also check [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more information on using ImageIO to load images.